# Logging and expected Exceptions during testing

Tags: testing, exception, logging, spock

In my app code it is common that where something goes wrong during app use I want as much information as possible about the circumstances to be logged, including if applicable the stack trace of an `Exception` which has been thrown.

But during testing I don't want these stack traces to be logged, cluttering up the log file to no purpose.

If this is a situation where the test itself creates an `Exception` object you can potentially give it a message which can identify it as a dummy `Exception`, like so:

```
given:
    indexMgr.queryParser = Mock( QueryParser ){
        parse(_) >> { throw new Exception( 'dummy parse problem' )}
    }
```

and then in the app code do this:

```
try {
    query = queryParser.parse(queryString)
}catch( e ) {
    log.debug( "QP exception msg: $e.message" )

    // we don't want a stack trace to be logged if this is a dummy Exception deliberately thrown during testing
    if( ! e.message.contains( 'dummy' )) {
        // this will log the stack trace of e
        log.error( 'query threw Exception in QP.parse()', e )
    }
    return false
}
```

... but there are 2 problems with this: firstly it is not always the case that an expected `Exception` will be created by the testing code, rather than by the app code, and secondly that it feels wrong to be checking for conditions identifying the conduct of a test in the actual app code.

Is there a "best practice" way of tackling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just dropping a stack trace from a line is fine, you can configure the exception conversion logic in a logger's pattern layout. Below is an example using log4j2:

```
public class ExceptionOutput {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionOutput.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Foo", new NullPointerException("MESSAGE"));
    }
}
```

log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
                           alwaysWriteExceptions="false"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Take note of `alwaysWriteExceptions=false`. It disables exceptions output completely. Now if we run the code we will get:

```
01:04:50.151 [main] INFO  ExceptionOutput - Foo
```

But if you revert to `alwaysWriteExceptions=true`, which is also the default behaviour if the parameter is omitted, then you get:

```
01:07:03.018 [main] INFO  ExceptionOutput - Foo
java.lang.NullPointerException: MESSAGE
    at ExceptionOutput.main(ExceptionOutput.java:8)
```

But there is more to this. For more flexibility you can use `%throwable{...}` conversion word in the pattern as explained [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) in the Patterns table for the respective conversion pattern. In order to apply the logic only to tests you can have log4j2-test.xml on your classpath as explained [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration). Similar functionality of exceptions conversion also exists for other logging libraries, e.g. [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord)

Comment: Thanks ... very helpful.  I suppose a finer-grained solution is likely to be impossible without some contrived mechanism for telling the app code that a test is under way.  It's just that you probably want unexpected Exceptions (both in test and app code) to be properly logged... but to suppress expected ones.